# require() does not work even when i change the type from module to common, I am new to this so maybe I am missing something

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

require() does not work even when I change the type from module to common, I am new to this so maybe I am missing something that I cannot put my hands on it

i tried const express = require('express'); ==> does not work

import express from 'express'; ==> worked

so i tried to change the type in package.js to common but still require did not work

Comment: [does not work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem

Answer (score -1):

By default if you dont specify **type** keyword in package.json node js will use CommonJS module system(i.e require() syntax) or you can give the **type** value as **commonjs** or **module**

```
"type":"commonjs"
```